# Programmatically deallocate memory in libstagrab

Tags: c++, c, stat

When and how do we free the memory when using `libstatgrab`. I didn't see any function call like `sg_free` that deallocates the memory object for storing the system statistics. For example:

```
sg_init(1);
sg_drop_privileges()
sg_load_stats *load_stat;
while(load_stat = sg_get_load_stats(NULL) != NULL) {
  cout << load_stat->min1 << load_stat->min5 << load_stat->min15);
}
```

The above while loop keeps calling the `sg_get_load_stats` function to get the cpu load. Does it use internal buffer or create a new one every time it is called? If the later is true, shouldn't we free the object? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Documentation](http://www.i-scream.org/libstatgrab/docs/sg_get_load_stats.3.html) appears to state that sg_get_load_stats() has local scope and is handled by the libstatgrab library.

sg_get_load_stats_r(), which is presumably used to return the value of the stats out of the current scope, dynamically allocates and the resulting buffer needs to be cleaned up by the user.